# Интеграционные тесты запущенные через Jenkins все время success вне зависимости от результатов самих тестов

Tags: spring, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция

Приложение на spring+maven+tomcat+jenkins.

После сборки и установки war-файла, следующим шагом прогоняю автотесты.

Если все выполнить локально, то тесты ведут себя адекватно.
Если запускать через Jenkins той же командой, то есть:

```
mvn test -Dgroups="integration.Integrations" -DenvConfig="at1"
```

, то тесты всегда проходят, даже когда какой-то тест намеренно сломан.

- `integration.Integrations` - это категория для тестов (интеграционные)
- `DenvConfig="at1"` - имя property-файла для тестов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Заметил такой момент, что если собираю локально командой mvn clean package,  то в target/testClasses есть скомпилированные тестовые классы и файлы со свойствами, в то время, как если заглянуть в workspace на Jenkins, то там только файлы со свойствами без самих компилированных классов.

Answer (score 0):

Добавил в pom.xml

```
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <testSourceDirectory>
            src/test
        </testSourceDirectory>
```